# Optimise animations with CSS3

Tags: jquery, performance, css, jquery-animate

Does, or will, jQuery ever leverage the performance improvements of CSS3 animations for it's `.animate()`, `.slideDown()`, `.fadeIn()`, etcetera functions? It would be nice to see it implemented already somewhere or implemented in jQuery itself soon.

Obviously it's limited to what CSS3 can do, but that's still a majority of effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the **[jQuery Animate Enhanced](https://github.com/benbarnett/jQuery-Animate-Enhanced)** project.

I don't think it wraps `.slideDown()` or `.fadeIn()`, but you can mimic those with `.animate()`.